# What is differnce between Geocoder and LocationManager?

Tags: android

Please, what is difference between GeoCoder and LocationManager? in Android development

Answer (score 1):

[Geocoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) has two methods to get a location from *any* known coords and vice versa.

[LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) is for asking the system the current (or the last known) position of *the device* via a provider (various networks, gps, etc)

Answer (score 0):

LocationManager is a framework class that allows you to request location information from a variety of sources-  network, GPS, etc.  It only deals with location in latitude and longitude terms.  Geocoding is about translating a latitude/longitude into a location like the Empire State Building or the local mall.